# "Oops! Something bad happened" and then unable to chat

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

I received a [chat invitation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/129205) that resulted in **Oops! Something bad happened!** when clicked (same result after a few retries). I then opened the link in a Chrome incognito window successfully, and was then able to open it in the normal window, which showed this:

[image]

When I clicked **join 1 user in this room now**, the window showed the chat transcript but provided no input for me to respond:

[image]

The footer indicates that I need to be "logged in to talk":

[image]

Clicking **logged in** shows that I'm already logged in:

[image]

Clicking **Google** to attempt to re-signin brings me back to the post-join screen (2nd screenshot).

I'm using Chrome 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit) on macOS Sierra 10.12. How do I fix this?

Comment: Should be fixed. I've removed the orphaned chat user. If you try going into chat again it should recreate a new user and associate it to your account and work.